# How to fix SQLSTATE[42000] error; using prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to create an email confirmation script.

Here is my PHP code:

```php
...
$q = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `email_confirm` (UserID,token,tokenDate) VALUES(:id, :token, UTC_TIMESTAMP()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE token = VALUES(:token), tokenDate = UTC_TIMESTAMP();");
$result = $q -> execute( array( ":id" => $this->id, ":token" => $token ) );
...
```

When this runs, I receive the following error:

```
 Caught exception: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?), tokenDate = UTC_TIMESTAMP()' at line 1
```

I'm no expert in MySQL, but I couldn't find any syntax errors in my code, and I would love some help.

Comment: the `values()` function does NOT need to have its own placeholder, or a duplicate placeholder. just use the name of the field you provided the value for originally: `insert into ... (foo,...) values($foo, ...) on duplicate key set foo=values(foo)`. mysql will look into the `values($foo,....)` section and pull the value provided there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented under [PDO::prepare](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

> You must include a unique parameter marker for each value you wish to pass in to the statement when you call [PDOStatement::execute()](https://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php). You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on.

Whilst you could add a `:token2` placeholder or similar that happens to be bound to the same value, actually MySQL's [`VALUES()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) function in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause takes a column name not a literal.  Therefore this will do the trick:

```
$q = $dbh->prepare('
  INSERT INTO email_confirm
    (UserID, token, tokenDate)
  VALUES
    (:id, :token, UTC_TIMESTAMP())
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    token = VALUES(token),
    tokenDate = UTC_TIMESTAMP()
');
```

However, you may want to look into [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/timestamp-initialization.html), rather than trying to reimplement the wheel.